# Saving a document with a sub-document gives duplicate key error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is the schema for the sub document.

```
const MainProcessSchema=new mongoose.Schema({    
        processID:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
        processName:{type:String,required:true},
        description:{type:String,required:true},
        subProcess:[
            {
                index:{type:Number},
                subProcessID:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'sub-process'},
            }
        ],
        steps:[
            {
                stepNo:{type:String,required:true},
                stepType:{type:String,
                    enum:{
                        values:['image','video'],
                        message:'{VALUE} should be image or video'
                    },
                    required:true}
            }
                
            ]
    })
```

This is the Document I have been trying to save using Equipment.create(req.body), but I get duplicate key error of processList.processID:null after sucessfully saving one document.

```
const EquipmentSchema=new mongoose.Schema<Equipment>({
    Id:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
    Name:{type:String,required:true}
    Details:{type:String},
    processList:[{type:MainProcessSchema,required:false}]

})

export const Equipment=model<Equipment>('equipment',EquipmentSchema);
```

I want to save the Equipment document which might contain processList or might not but its not required unless the processID is filled up.

Answer (score 0):

insted a unique base index you have to do use a custom index that don't count null values, in your case using this:

```
 schema.index({ processID: 1 }, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { processID: { $type: 'string' } } });
```

the expression partialFilterExpression allow you to count only strings and not null values

Comment: Can you help me where to write this ? I have written like this `MainProcessSchema.index({ processID: 1 }, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { processID: { $type: 'string' } } });` Still this shows up as error for duplicate key

Comment: the sintax is correct, you have to manual remove from the db the old index. (using a program like studio 3t or similars). because if you keep it it will continue running. and don't forget to remove unique true in processId from schema

Comment: Can you explain it to me with a piece of code, it would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: you set a index on processId that is unique and only a string (null values are not insert into this index but only string values)